# setting a timer for a label in Java

Tags: java, timer, timertask

Currently, I am developing an ATM simulation and there are mainly three functions, which are "display balance", "withdraw money" and "deposit money". As it is just a simulation, there is no cash dispenser and because of this reason, I assigned a random amount when the customer would like to deposit money to the account.

When it comes to my question, when the user clicks to the deposit money, there is a label in that screen. I want that label to write "counting money" for 2 seconds and then show the actual amount, which is randomly generated.

My problem is the first part. How can I let the label write "counting" for 2 seconds?

Thank you for your answers and time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swing provides a [timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) for this sort of thing, have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). For example:

```
label.setText("Counting");
Timer timer = new Timer(2000, e -> label.setText("Done"));
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

As a commenter pointed out it's `javax.swing.Timer` and not `java.util.Timer` you want as the former performs it's action on the EDT.

Comment: Should probably mention he shouldn't get it confused with `java.util.Timer`; tends to be a beginners trap

Comment: @brain thank you for your answer. It works stable. 
btw. at the end of the first line, ";" requires.

Comment: @KenVors I've put the ';' in.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have created a pane of choice(JPanel,JDesktopPane,etc) and made a similar JButton for the Deposit button and the JLabel for the label in which you want to show "Counting Money", you would need to create a `Thread` which will run in parallel with the other code in your program so that your program doesn't have to wait for the counting process till you can do something else. So, you would create a `Thread` object,  as shown below, and and get the current time using the code `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()` and set a `long` variable to hold the start time. Then using a `while` loop, you would keep checking the difference between the start time and the current time to see if 2 seconds have passed. Save this difference in another `long` variable inside the loop and make the loop check if its value has surpassed 2000 milliseconds(2 seconds). When the time exceeds 2 seconds the while loop stops, the `Thread` can move onto executing the next line of code which sets your label to nothing(You can change the text to whatever you want). After this the `Thread` stops. Your code should look something like this:

```
    JLabel lblCount = new JLabel("");
    lblCount.setBounds(92, 28, 243, 90);
    windowPane.add(lblClock);

    JButton btnDeposit = new JButton("Deposit Money");
    btnDeposit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            lblCount.setText("Counting Money.....Please Wait");
            long start = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            Thread timer = new Thread(){
                public void run()
                { 
                    long time = Long.valueOf(0);
                     while(time < Long.valueOf(2))
                     {
                         time = (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - start)/1000;
                     }

                     lblCount.setText("");
                }
            };
        }
    });
    btnDeposit.setBounds(78, 175, 118, 53);
    windowPane.add(btnDeposit);
```

Comment: There are two problems with this approach, the first is that you should not update the label in your own thread, only do it in the EDT. The second is that you are busy spinning, consuming CPU resources in order to do nothing. You can use Thread.sleep() in order to wait more efficiently.

Comment: @brain Oh thank you for pointing out the insufficiency of my code. I am relatively new to GUI programming and used whatever I thought was the only way :D. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

```
public void crono() {
    TimerTask tarea = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int ok = 0;
            if (actualTime < maxTime * 1000) {
                ok = 1;
                //because its in miliseconds
                actualTime = actualTime + 1000;
            }

            switch (ok) {
                case 1:
                    int displayTime= actualTime/ 1000;
                    label.setText(Integer.toString(displayTime));
                    break;
                //if actual is over maxtime
                case 0:
                    label.setText("TIME IS UP");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

    };
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tarea, 0, 1000);

//the first argument will be the task, the second the starting time, and the final one is //the period, in this case it will be one second



}
```

Comment: Write a few words explaining it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Threads.

```
Thread t; 
t = new Thread(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    label.setText("counting...");
    Thread.sleep(2000);//Time in Milliseconds
    label.setText("Display what you want.");
  }
}
t.start();
```

Comment: This is wrong because because you are updating swing components on a different thread to the Event Dispatch Thread. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Comment: But you can do it :D And you can't do Thread.sleep in the main Thread because then you can't interact with the other components of the frame

Comment: yes you can do it but you shouldn't. Swing does provide a lot of things that help you with concurrency. Your solution just needs the label updating to be done via SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater and it would work.